# Convert an Image DataUrl to Blob in JavaScript with Webkit Fallback?

Tags: javascript, html, image, blob

I have an image represented as data URL. I want this image to be converted into a blob.

I use the following method for this purpose:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var _ia = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        _ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
    var blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: mimeString });
    return blob;
}
```

This function is working but as I found here: [Blob support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls) the blob sometimes need the webkit prefix to work. I know that for URL I could use the fallback with

```
var _URL = URL || webkitURL;
```

**How do I have to include the webkit prefix version as a fallback for older browsers in my function? Do I have to use BlobBuilder() instead on Blob()?**

Comment: You only need the webkit prefix for Blackberry 10. Just out of curiously, do you really have Blackberry 10 users?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to feature detect support for Blob is `try` and `catch`

```
function supportsBlob() {
    try {
        return !!new Blob();
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just `!!window.Blob` ?